# Checking old data against new and only processing actual changed values in google app scripts on sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

I have a sheet that scrapes information from another sheet and organizes it into 3 sheets (70%, 80%, 90%). My current `onChange` script works, but fires any time there is any change to any cell and not just if the percentage for a client changes; currently I'm getting a lot of repeated emails with the same information. Is there a way to store the previous row values and check against them and only process what's new?

Here's what I'm trying, but the script debugger keeps coming back with `TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 12, file "Code")`. I know it's because `oldData` is currently empty, and I'm stuck on what to do to make it work. If anyone could help or at least point me in the direction of a better way would be a great help.

```
function notification70() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //”0″ is the first sheet
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process-actual row# (this is cell A1)
    var numRows = 10; // Number of rows to process (goes from A1-A10)
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3) //set range
    var formats = dataRange.getNumberFormats(); //get the format style of the cells
    dataRange.setNumberFormats(formats); //set the format of the array to the same as the data (currently not working)
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i]; //convert data to var to row for easier memory on what I'm writing
        if (row[i] = oldData[i]) continue; //if current data percentage = the previous then skip
        var emailAddress = "email@email.com"; // Email
        var percent = row[1]*100; //convert to % value
        var percentage = parseFloat(percent).toFixed(2); //cut to 2 decimal points
        var message = "You have now reached 70% of your time for " + row[0] + ". You are currently at " + percentage + "% for " + row[0] + ". Keep up the good work."; // emails the information for the row schanged
        var subject = "You have reached 70% of the time for " + row[0] + ". #Notification"; //email subject

        if (percent != 0) Logger.log(emailAddress + "\n" + subject + "\n" + message); //log the output for testing

    }
   var oldData = data //update/save current values for next script run
}
```

The sheet data looks like this and will :

```
      Client   |     Percentage   |        Date
   ---------------------------------------------------
      BBB      |      78.19%      |      1/18/2016
   ---------------------------------------------------
      DDD      |      79.63%      |      1/18/2016
   ---------------------------------------------------
      FFF      |      74.54%      |      1/18/2016
   ---------------------------------------------------
      KKK      |      72.30%      |      1/18/2016
   ---------------------------------------------------
      MMM      |      71.47%      |      1/18/2016
   ---------------------------------------------------
      PPP      |      73.39%      |      1/18/2016
```

Thank you all for the help ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the "old data" into the document properties.  Either that, or create a new sheet tab for the "old data".  It looks like you aren't getting that much data, so it might fit into a property of the document properties.

```
function storeRowsOfData(data) {

  var objOldData = {};
  var keyName = "",
      thisRowArray;

  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1) {
    keyName = "row" + (i+2).toString();
    thisRowArray = data[i].toString();

    objOldData[keyName] = thisRowArray;
  };

  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperties(objOldData, true); //true deletes all other properties
};
```

If you don't delete all other properties, and the length of the rows on the current action were less than the last, you would have left over rows from the old, old data.  If you are not using document properties for anything else, and don't have an Add-on that uses document properties, then you'll be okay.

### Code:

```
function getRowsOfOldData() {
  var oldValues = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();

  var outerArrayOldData = [];
  var thisLoopString,
      thisRowArray;

  for (var key in oldValues) {
    thisLoopString = oldValues[key];
    thisRowArray = []; //Reset
    thisRowArray = thisLoopString.split(","); //Convert the string to an array

    outerArrayOldData.push(thisRowArray);//Push the inner array into the outer array
  };

  Logger.log('outerArrayOldData: ' + outerArrayOldData);
};
```

The function to get the data, puts all the data back into a two dimensional array.  That's it's original form.  The function to put the data into the document properties, did not put all the data into one property, but into multiple properties.   When something is put into document properties, it is converted to a string.  You can not store data as an array or object in document properties.  And, putting each row into it's own property avoids any issues with data limitations per property setting.

Comment: Will this update after the first script fires and update the values? And what Trigger would you set it to, cron or other?

Comment: I showed a function name just for the sake of showing some context.  You can copy out the contents of that function, and put that code into your original code.  You can call that function, and pass in `data`.  I'm just showing a section of code, that shows an option for permanent storage.  Also, I didn't show the code that would get the data out.  If you want to have a seperate function that stores the data, which is a good idea, all you need to do is add a line of code in your main function:  `storeRowsOfData(data)` somewhere after `data` is retrieved.

Comment: this option seems like the best way to store the values long term, the actual % values only change once or twice a week. I just don't know how to use the document properties yet. Will have to read on how to store and pull the information and then create a function like above for storing it all and pulling it `onchange` to see if the value changed. Thanks for a new direction to check out, just hope it's as easy as the regular scripting I already know lol.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  If you consider this the correct answer you can check it as correct.  You can also post questions in the [Google Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) if it's not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried using this, but when I call the document properties and set as oldData `var oldData = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();`  it returns the value as `DocumentProperties`

Comment: See updated answer with new function to get the values.

Comment: this worked good, now I just have to figure out how to test each row vs the old data row

Answer (score 0):

For the error: add var oldData = []; before the for loop to define it.

Comment: Won't that reset it to a blank array every time it fires?

Comment: Hmm yeah. if(!oldData) var oldData = [];

Comment: everytime I run the script it resets the data even with `if(!oldData)`. Does app script wipe variable after each script run?